# JMS connection to remote client

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms

I'm trying to test a JMS Application, I don't have a problem with the consumer , but when I try to run the producer which have the following code

```
public class QueueProducer {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws NamingException
     * @throws JMSException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JMSException, NamingException {
        System.out
                .println("--------Entering JMS Example QueueProducer--------");
        Context context = QueueConsumer.getInitialContext();
        QueueConnectionFactory queueConnectionFactory = (QueueConnectionFactory) context
                .lookup("ConnectionFactory");
        Queue queue = (Queue) context
                .lookup("queue/zaneacademy_jms_tutorial_02");
        QueueConnection queueConnection = queueConnectionFactory
                .createQueueConnection();
        QueueSession queueSession = queueConnection.createQueueSession(false,
                QueueSession.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        queueConnection.start();
        QueueProducer queueProducer = new QueueProducer();
        queueProducer.sendMessage("Message 1 From QueueProducer...",
                queueSession, queue);
        System.out.println("--------Exiting JMS Example QueueProducer--------");
    }

    public void sendMessage(String text, QueueSession queueSession, Queue queue)
            throws JMSException {
        QueueSender queueSender = queueSession.createSender(queue);
        TextMessage textMessage = queueSession.createTextMessage(text);
        queueSender.send(textMessage);
        System.out.println("Message Sent : "+textMessage.getText());
        queueSender.close();
    }

}
```

It display just the message in producer, after a few seconds it display this warning

```
 WARN  [SimpleConnectionManager] A problem has been detected with the connection to remote client 5c4o12-  tsh1gl-hfybsrs4-1-hfybss2a-4, jmsClientID=b-l5ssbyfh-1-4srsbyfh-lg1hst-21o4c5. It is possible the client has exited without closing its connection(s) or the network has failed. All associated connection resources will be cleaned up.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the queue connection needs to be closed. Try adding `queueConnection.close();` at the end of `main`.

In addition, resources that need to be closed should be done in a finally block. This ensures the resource is closed even if an exception occurs while working with the resource. For example:

```
QueueSender queueSender = ...
try {
    // use queueSender
}
finally {
    queueSender.close();
}
```

Same thing for `queueConnection`.

Comment: Thank you , it works 
But still have a little problem , which is when i run the producer , it's send , but the consumer doesn't receive it

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue. I think QueueConnection and QueueSession need to close.In above code snippet, addtional code should be :

```
        queueConnection.stop();
        queuesession.close();
        queueConnection.close();
```

My issue got resolved after this.